# Is Mac OS X really SUS compliant?

Tags: osx, utilities

Internet says that Mac OS X 10.8 *[has achieved certification to The Open Group UNIX® 03 standard](http://blog.opengroup.org/2012/07/25/apple-registers-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-to-the-unix-03-standard/)* and that it *[is a compliant system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#OS_X)*.

But a simple test with `echo` seems to indicate otherwise:

**a)** [The Base Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/echo.html) states

> Implementations **shall not** support any options.

and

> IEEE Std 1003.1-2001/Cor 1-2002, item XCU/TC1/D6/21 is applied, so that the echo utility can accommodate historical BSD behavior.

**b)** [The man page says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/echo.1.html) states

> **SYNOPSIS** 
>        echo [-n] [string ...]

and

> **STANDARDS** 
>        The echo utility conforms to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'') as amended by Cor. 1-2002.

**c)** The reality is that it supports options. At least `e`

```
(user@avitus tmp)$ uname -a
Darwin avitus.local 12.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
(user@avitus tmp)$ echo -e "test \tAm I SUS compliant?"
test    Am I SUS compliant?
(user@avitus tmp)$ echo "test \tAm I SUS compliant?"
test \tAm I SUS compliant?
```

So, the questions are:
 **1. Does this break compliance?**

 **2. Is Mac OS X 10.8 really SUS compliant?**

 **3. Does the part** *item XCU/TC1/D6/21 is applied, so that the echo utility can accommodate historical BSD behavior.* **have something to do? If so, where is that item explained? The** 
[Technical Corrigendum Number  1 for the Austin Group Specifications](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_155.txt) **doesn't say much.**

 **4. Am I missing something?**

Comment: I have seen http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819 and
http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/

Comment: How silly....
Was using bash !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OS X 10.8 is also listed as a UNIX 03 registered product in http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/.

If you are using bash, it is not POSIX-compliant by default. echo doesn't support any options by default in sh though.

```
$ bash
$ builtin echo -e a; /bin/echo -e a
a
-e a
$ sh
$ builtin echo -e a; /bin/echo -e a
-e a
-e a
$ shopt -u xpg_echo
$ builtin echo -e a; /bin/echo -e a
a
-e a
```

[OS X's sh is a version of bash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/are-bash-bourne-and-korn-shells-compiled-into-one-binary-in-osx) with differences like:

- [POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) is enabled
- xpg_echo is enabled (echo doesn't support any options and interprets escape sequences)
- sh -l doesn't read .bash_profile
- FCEDIT defaults to ed instead of EDITOR or ed